# Render MUI components to string client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using the Material UI (MUI) library as a basis for my React app and I am trying to render some of the components to PDF *in the browser*.

The strategy is:

1. Create a React element
2. Render the React element to an HTML string
3. Render the HTML string as a PDF

My code currently:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

// ...

const el = (
  <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(el);

const doc = new jsPDF({
  orientation: "portrait",
  unit: "px",
});

const callback = () => {
  doc.save("test.pdf");
};

doc.html(html, { callback });
```

However, this does not render the theme correctly (fonts, background colors, etc). I believe this is an issue with step (2).

MUI uses Emotion for CSS styling, but the SSR packages for Emotion only seem to work on Node.

```js
import { renderStylesToString } from '@emotion/server';
```

How can I render the styles into a complete HTML string in the browser?

---

Some versions:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
"@emotion/css": "^11.7.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be extracting the styles manually:

```js
function extractCSS() {
    return [...document.styleSheets]
      .map((styleSheet) => {
        try {
          return [...styleSheet.cssRules].map((rule) => rule.cssText).join("");
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      })
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join("");
  }
```